# how to pass a template's data to another template using iron router (not on query parameter)

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I m new to iron router and want to pass one template'data to the calling template through Router.go() method. But i found it can be pass through query but i don't want to use query as my data is large JSON object.
So, is there a way to pass data from one template to another template using iron-router.
any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Save it to some local collection then use the ID in the url is one way.

```
JSONCollection = new Mongo.Collection('some_json');

Template.yourTemplate.events({
  'click button[data-action="go-to-next"]': function (e, template) {
    var id = JSONCollection.insert(template.data);
    Router.go('yourroute', { _id: id });
  }
});
```

Then your url will just contain the id.

> /yourroute/:someIdHere

Answer (score 1):

Use [Session.set()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_set) before calling Router.go() and [Session.get()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_get) on another template. This approach doesn't require round trip to database but be sure to not flooding Session object as it will persist throughout browser session.